# Extract lines under the specified heading

Tags: javascript, array, state-machine

I wrote the following working code, which I just can't stomach:

```
var data = [
    { id: 0, isHeading: true, description: "A heading" },
    { id: 1, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 1" },
    { id: 2, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 2" },
    { id: 3, isHeading: true, description: "A heading" },
    { id: 4, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 3" },
    { id: 5, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 4" },
    { id: 7, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 5" },
    { id: 8, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 6" },
    { id: 9, isHeading: true, description: "A heading" },
    { id: 10, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 7" },
    { id: 11, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 8" },
    { id: 12, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 9" },
    { id: 13, isHeading: true, description: "A heading" },
    { id: 14, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 10" },
    { id: 15, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 11" },
    { id: 16, isHeading: true, description: "A heading" },
    { id: 17, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 12" },
    { id: 18, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 13" },
    { id: 19, isHeading: false, description: "Blah 14" }
  ]
  function getLines (headingId) {
    var r = []
    var inThere = false
    for (let line of data) {
      if (line.isHeading) {
        if(line.id === headingId) {
          inThere = true
          continue
        } else if (line.id !== headingId && inThere) {
          return r
        }
      }
      if (inThere) r.push(line)
    }
    return r
  }
  getLines(9)
```

Basically, it's taking a chunk of a list; it's a state automaton where the `inThere` state is set by a matching heading ID, and the routine is done when either there are no more items, or a new heading comes up.

Is there a much better way of writing this?

Comment: It would be nice if you could replace the _Blah_ dummy data with some real data from your working environment, so we get an idea how you would use this function.

Comment: @200_success you suggest a state machine solution to this problem?

Comment: @dfhwze No, I'm just tagging the question according to the author's own characterization of the code as a state automaton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unless you know of the top of your head every instance that automatic semicolon insertion can fail (there are a few) you should use semicolons.
- Always use `{}` to delimit a statement block, even if it is one line. It is very easy to overlook the missing `{}` if you make changes and its not easy to spot the error when you look for the bug.
- The array `r` can be a constant
- The variable line in he loop can be a constant;
- `r` is a very poor name, maybe `result` would be better?
- `inThere` is a very poor name, maybe `headingFound` has more meaning?
- `getLines` has no meaning, maybe `sectionByHeadingId` ( I don't know what it represents so the section part is a guess)
- You are accessing a global scoped object `data` try to avoid such access by passing the array as a argument
- Avoid undue complication.

  - Don't execute statement if not needed. The statement `if (inThere)` can be  `} else if (inThere)`
  - Don't repeat the same return if there is a shorter way. Replace the inner return with `break`,
  - Don't test a state you know. You test  `if(line.id === headingId) {` then in the following `else` you check its state again `else if (line.id !== headingId` The first statement has already determined if the line is heading id you can only get to the else if `line.id !== headingId` is true

### Example

Rewrites your code

```
function sectionByHeadingId(sections, headingId) {
    const result = [];
    var headingFound = false;
    for (const line of sections) {
        if (line.isHeading) {
            if (line.id === headingId) { 
                headingFound = true;
            } else if (headingFound) { 
                break;
            }
        } else if (headingFound) { 
            result.push(line);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
sectionByHeadingId(data, 9);
```

### Example2

An alternative and simpler solution by using `Array.findIndex` to find the start of the section you want. Then you need only push lines till the next heading or end of array

```
function sectionByHeadingId(sections, headingId) {
    const result = [];
    var idx = sections.findIndex(line => line.id === headingId) + 1;
    while (sections[idx] && !sections[idx].isHeading) { 
        result.push(sections[idx++]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Picked this one mainly for the fantastic rewrite at the bottom. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

- Your function skips until the heading is found and than takes element until the next heading. Perhaps we could split these methods up to make them **reusable**.
- Try to avoid `var` (undesired scope), prefer `let` or `const` instead.
- Prefer a Tree data structure over flat list for hierarchical data.

#### Refactored for Reusability

Skip items while a predicate is true.

```
  function skipWhile(items, predicate) {
    let ok = false;
    return items.filter((value, index, array) => {
      if (!ok && !predicate(value)){
        ok = true;
      }
      return ok;
    });
  };
```

Take items while a predicate is true.

```
  function takeWhile(items, predicate) {
    let ok = true;
    return items.filter((value, index, array) => {
      if (ok && !predicate(value)){
        ok = false;
      }
      return ok;
    });
  };
```

The OP method:

```
 function getLines (headingId) {
    let lines = skipWhile(data, v => v.id != headingId);
    lines.shift(); // we don't want the heading
    lines = takeWhile(lines, v => !v.isHeading);
    return lines;
  }
```

And verification:

```
  console.log(getLines(9).map(x => x.description))
```

Yielding:

> (3) [ "Blah 7" , "Blah 8" , "Blah 9" ]

You could also create these methods as prototype extensions on `Array` or refactor them to become generator functions (with *yield* syntax). I am sure these methods could get optimized for performance somehow.